# I am using PHP ODBC to write to an access database, but it won't write to the database

Tags: php, mysql, database, ms-access

I'm trying to use PHP/ODBC to connect to an access file. The problem is that I can read from the database but I can't write to it using the below:

```
$conn = odbc_connect('SKW-DB','','');
if (!$conn)
   {
    exit ("ODBC Connection Failed ". $conn);
   }
$stmt = "INSERT INTO PRODUCT (ProductCode, ProductName) VALUES ('TestCode', 'TestEntry')";
$result = odbc_exec ($conn,$stmt);
echo "Result1: ";
echo $result;
```

$result returns nothing. Again, I am able to read from the database, connectivity isn't an issue. I just can't write to it.

Comment: "`$result returns nothing.`" Nothing or `false`?

Comment: What do you expect the `$result` to be? [According to the documentation](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-exec.php), it returns a resource which I doubt you can echo.

Comment: In the resulting page all that shows up is "Result1: ". Nothing after. Not really expecting it to be anything really, just noted that in case it would help solve the issue.

Comment: It is probably because the [user doesn't have permission](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/175168) to write to the database.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you're simply ASSUMING the query can never fail. It did fail, and returned a boolean false. `echo false` literally prints out nothing.

Try this instead:

```
$result = odbc_exec($conn, $stmt);
if ($result === false ) {
   die(odbc_errormsg($conn));
}
```

And what you get back from odbc_exec() cannot be echoed out anyways. On success, it returns a statement handle, which is NOT something you can simply print out.

Comment: "[Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Operation must use an updateable query" is what I get out of that.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need a little more debugging code.

First, try `var_dump`ing the `$result` instead of `echo`ing it.

```
var_dump($result);
```

There's certain PHP variable types that `echo` can't/won't display.

Next -- chances are your query's causing an error of some sort, so try using the `odbc` error reporting functions after making your query

```
$result = odbc_exec ($conn,$stmt);
echo "Result1: ";
var_dump( $result );
if($result)
{
    var_dump( odbc_error($conn)    );    
    var_dump( odbc_errormsg($conn) );
}
```